# How can I edit a php custom page template to work in other themes?

Tags: php, page-template, theme-customizer

How do I edit a php custom page template to work in another wordpress theme? Do I just have to take out the header codes or do I have to edit a whole php page?

Header area
[image]
[image]

Thank you for any input. 
Kimberly

Comment: It depends entirely on the theme you're adding it to. You would would need to refer to their standard page templates and adjust to match as much as possible.

Comment: I would add them to any theme that worked. I prefer Divi but at this point I've given up and trying to figure a new way to set this up.  Thanks